# MS map point web service

Tags: bing-maps

can anybody plz guide me through following questions

- do MS Map point also covers India???
- how we can use MS map point web service or API's or library etc to get the current location based on input Lat and Longitude.
- is there  some facility of defining our custom maps and can we define our custom milestones on the custom map.

Answer (score 0):

- [Coverage](http://www.spatialpoint.com/Virtual-Earth-Coverage.aspx)
- if you know lat/long, don't you already *know* the location?
- no, I don't think you can define custom maps; but you should be able to add custom data